How can I do GAM piecewise in R?
I have some data $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^N$ which looks like a sigmoid curve in the xy-plane. Kind of like this:

I think my data is homoscedastic normal distributed.

My data has much larger variance than this figure, but the general shape in the $xy$-plane is not far off. I think it's suitable for GAM with cubic spline for intermediate values of the explanatory variable ($x$).
As a matter of fact of the experiment, I know that for small and large values of $x$s, the $y$s are constant. So I want to use a cubic spline in the non-constant region, and a constant spline $y(x) = \overline{x}$ in the constant region.
I have experience with fitting qubic spline-GAM with mgcv in R.

Can I use different degree splines for different regions of the explanatory variable using GAM in R? If so, how can I do it? If it's not possible, what seems the most rational way to fit this data in R?

Questions about coding and software are off topic here, but if you edit your question so it emphasizes statistical aspects, it may be OK.  But if you really want to know just how to do this in R, then you should look at an R list, or the package maintainers.

Just get rid of the question if you think that improves the website

What you are interested in doing here is forcing the smooth to be monotonically increasing, where the slope of the smooth function at any point along the covariate $x$ must be non-negative. There are some helpful posts on this topic that you can refer to, i.e.:
How to smooth data and force monotonicity
and
Extrapolating from a smooth monotonic curve in R. I suggest you refer to those and the help pages from the {mgcv} and {scam} packages to get you started.

Not exactly what I asked for. But it works great if I have a bespoke knot placement. Thanks!
